# Adobe Flex and Air Connecting to a network

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, air

What Approach can you use to Connect Adobe Air Application to a Local Network? Examples of function is send a message to other computer that is connected to a network, sending files or viewing their desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: viewing their desktop with AIR - ambitious!!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could get help from [this guy](http://www.wizhelp.com/flashlight-vnc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Media Server. With Flash Media Server you can do it but it is not free. Free version of FMS is Red5. This guy make project like you want and check it http://nocreativity.com/blog/hello-preso